# What is the difference between #> and ->> operator in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We can access any JSON element in PostgreSQL 9.3 using the `->` and `->>` operators. Seems to me that the `#>` along with `#>>` only provide a shorter form of writing the JSON path. Or is there a bigger picture behind the `#>` operator? Does it serve a special purpose/provide any advantage over the arrow notation? Which one is the preffered method of writing paths?

It all comes to the question: why should I use the `#>` and `#>>` operator over the `->` and `->>`?

[The docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) are a bit enigmatic about this.

Both queries below give the same result:

```
=> select '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>'{a,2}';
 ?column? 
----------
 3

=> select '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json->'a'->>2;
 ?column? 
----------
 3
```

Answer (score 11):

Consider nesting.

```
{
  "a" : {
    "b" : {
      "c" : 1,
      "d" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

Imagine that you have a json document, and you *don't know in advance how it will be nested*. If you knew you needed a three level path, you could write:

```
SELECT '{
  "a" : {
    "b" : {
      "c" : 1,
      "d" : 2
    }
  }
}'::json -> 'a' -> 'b' -> 'c';
```

but what if you want to write a query that doesn't know that in advance? That's where the path-based operators are useful; the path can be supplied along with the document, and there's no longer any assumption about the document structure in the query.

```
SELECT '{
  "a" : {
    "b" : {
      "c" : 1,
      "d" : 2
    }
  }
}'::json #>> ARRAY['a','b','c']
```